# hideColumns and getVIewColumns with Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to show/hide columns in a columnChart but things don't work as expected.

This is my chart (which works fine):

```
function drawGraph() {
        $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "./functions.php",
                data: { action: 'draw_bar_chart'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(jsonData) {
                data_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);
                var options = jsonData[1]['options'];

                // Instantiate and draw the chart
                chartColumn = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
                data_chart.getViewColumns();
                chartColumn.draw(data_chart, options);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, `getViewColumns` returns `data_chart.getViewColumns is not a function`

And here is how I intend to hide the button after I've got working `getViewColumns`

```
$('.toggle_button').click(function () {
            data_chart.hideColumns([1]); // To be adjusted
            chart.draw(data_chart, options);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of the following methods are members of the [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView)...

```
getViewColumns()
hideColumns(columnIndexes)
```

and **do not exist** on the [DataTable Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)...

to correct, you could convert the data table to a data view...

```
data_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);

// convert data table to data view
data_chart = new google.visualization.DataView(data_chart);

var options = jsonData[1]['options'];

// Instantiate and draw the chart
chartColumn = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
data_chart.getViewColumns();
chartColumn.draw(data_chart, options);
```

Comment: so easy! thanks! I didn't figure out the ´´´hideColumns´´´ link jumped to DataView Class...